# How do I get the number of GTK TreeView columns that will fit in a given area?

Tags: gtk

I am writing a GTK program that uses a TreeView which is expected to represent a very large number of elements. To improve performance, I have decided not to keep them all in the backing ListStore, but instead to just show enough elements to fit on the screen, and use a "fake" scroll bar to clear and refill the backing ListStore based on the position of the "fake" scroll bar. For scrolling to work correctly, **I need to know precisely how many TreeView cells I can fit on the screen**.

For starters, I can't even seem to figure out how large the TreeView headers are. I tried this, but it didn't seem to work (possibly because in his case, he doesn't use any headers at all): [Get Pixel Position of Item or Cell Height in Treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674065/get-pixel-position-of-item-or-cell-height-in-treeview)

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the answer while writing the question, and I thought I'd post it here anyway.

Basically, **you need to set fixed-height mode before you insert your columns**. Then, you can compute the answer as follows:

```
// this is a hack to work around the fact that
// gtk_tree_view_get_effective_header_height() is a private function
// see: https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/6033b6457b1cf6c9ce173f9b34d56431ab49256e/gtk/gtktreeview.c#L13954
private int get_header_height() {
  int h = 0;

  if (this.get_headers_visible())
    this.convert_bin_window_to_widget_coords(0, 0, null, out h);

  return h;
}

// according to the documentation, the sum of background areas covered by
// each node adds up to the area of the entire bin window
private int get_cell_height() {
  Gdk.Rectangle rect = new Gdk.Rectangle();
  this.get_background_area(new TreePath.first(), this.get_column(0), out rect);
  return rect.height;
}

public int get_visible_columns() {
  assert(this.get_realized());

  return (int)GLib.Math.ceil((double)(this.get_allocated_height() - this.get_header_height()) / (double)this.get_cell_height());
}
```

I was getting incorrect results because not all of my rows were the same height. The difference was too small to tell at a glance though - I didn't notice until I took a screenshot of my program and opened it in GIMP.